# How do I encode a global Python variable with JSON?

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm trying to figure out how I can encode my globals into a JSON format, I'm not even sure if it's possible. I'm using Python 2.7.8, and I've tried this from a few different approaches:

```
# Variables
value = "String" # String
value2 = 0 # Integer
value3 = True # Boolean

json.dumps({"key": value, "key2": value2, "key3": value3}, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

I also tried making it a string first (with and without the curly braces, with/without quotations on the string value etc.)

```
json_raw = '{"key": %s, "key2": %d, "key3": %s}' % (value, value2, value3)
json.dumps(json_raw, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

However, with each one of these attempts I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me answer with code:

```
value = "String" # String
value2 = 0 # Integer
value3 = True # Boolean
json_map = {}
json_map["Some string"] = value
json_map["Some int"] = value2
json_map["Some bool"] = value3
result = json.dumps(json_map)
```

And then the result containts `'{"Some int": 0, "Some string": "String", "Some bool": true}'`. All thanks to the magic of [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json).

Comment: Awesome, I got it working with your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable. Reading your code, you're using the `json.dump` function. `dump` expects the second argument to be a file-like object. The `dumps` function, **note the s**, does not, and returns the JSON representation of the data as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry my code _does_ have `json.dumps` but I accidentally put `json.dump` in my question. This is helpful though, I'll keep it in mind for future reference.